# How to partition MySQL table for every id just like we do in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, partitioning

In our application for each query we build a unique query id, and insert to table according to this query id.
We used to use Hive for this and it was easy;

```
create table hivetable (
...
)PARTITIONED BY ( query_id INT ) ...
```

and inserting to table was like this:

```
alter table hivetable add partition (query_id=?);
insert into hivetable  partition(query_id=?) select ...;
```

And now we are migrating to MySQL and I am confused. I tried below table and insert like this:

```
create table mytable (...)  PARTITION BY HASH(query_id);

insert into mysql values(?,?,...,<query_id>);
```

Apperantly it didn't work in a way I wanted. It inserts the data of all query_ids in one partition.
So I would really appreciate some help
Thanks

Comment: I doubt that you need in partitioning in MySQL. Can you post the reasons for it?

Comment: Hi firstly thanks. Beside we insert, we select and also delete these records for query_id. So we need these operations to run in high speed.

Comment: If so then think about RANGE partitions, not HASH.

Comment: There is no benefit, only complexity in using Partitioning for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end Indexing worked well for me. We wanted to use smth like Hive partitioning because of fastening to select, delete operations. And I found indexing in MySQL is pretty corresponds our needs. If you index the columns which you use where statements, it will fasten your queries pretty well. You can find more info in following link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation on how to use [Mysql Partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html).  Here's an example of using hash.

***WARNING*:** If you do not include a PARTITIONS clause, the number of partitions defaults to 1.

```
    CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(30),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
    separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
    job_code INT,
    store_id INT
)
PARTITION BY HASH(store_id)
PARTITIONS 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use MySQL's `PARTITIONing` for this task.  Simply have the unique `query_id` be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then `INSERT tbl` or `UPDATE tbl` or `SELECT ... FROM tbl`, as appropriate.